# How to add a sortable column from the admin log in Django

Tags: django, annotations, django-admin, django-orm

In the Django admin area I need to display when an object was last modified by another user. Therefore I want to leverage Django’s built-in admin log. I came up with this solution:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...

    @property
    def admin_last_modified(self):
        from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry
        from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
        try:
            logentry = LogEntry.objects.filter(
                object_id=self.pk,
                content_type_id=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self.__class__)
            ).order_by('action_time')[0]
        except:
            return ''
        return '{} by {}'.format(logentry.action_time, logentry.user)
```

and the admin class:

```
@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ( ..., 'admin_last_modified' )
```

The disadvantage, which is a show-stopper for me, is that the column is not sortable.

For that, from what I’ve gathered, I'd need to re-formulate the property as some kind of annotation. But I’ve tried and haven’t come up with an idea how to do so:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

   def get_queryset(self):
       queryset = super().get_queryset(request)
       queryset = queryset.annotate(
           admin_last_modified=# ???
       )
       return queryset
```

I’m now looking for what to substitute the question marks with.

How can I write an annotation, that fetches one row of information from another basically unrelated table?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `LogEntry` objects, you could add an `DateField` with `auto_add` [as described here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now) and sort based on that - this will also record changes of the instance from outside of the admin panel (`LogEntry` only registers changes made through the admin panel).

Comment: Normally I’d do that, yes. But in my case I need specifically the “last modified AT by WHO” information, and additionally do not want to update a timestamp, when manipulating the object outside the admin area (e.g., batch processing on the CLI). Therefore I want to piggy-back onto the already existing log data, which exactly contains what I need.